# How to use the parameters? There is an @ symbol at the definition of \title

Tags: titles

What dose the symbol @ mean?
@checktitle and s@title.

How to use the two parameters?

```
\renewcommand{\title}[2][]{%
\gdef\@checktitle{#1}\ifx\@checktitle\empty\gdef\@title{#2}
\gdef\s@title{#2}\else\gdef\@title{#2}\gdef\s@title{#1}\fi}
```

Comment: See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351) (possible duplicate). You'll need the surrounding pair if you want to (re)define content with `@` in the control sequence/macro name.

Comment: How to use the macro \title?
What does this macro mean?
I think it can accept two parameters. How to pass these parameters?

Comment: `\title[<subtitle>]{<title>}` would be the usage, with `<subtitle>` being optional. That is, you can also just use `\title{<title>}`, which will make the subtitle the same as the title. Inside `\title`, the subtitle is stored in `\s@title` and the title inside `\@title`. `\@checktitle` is just temporary storage to see whether an empty subtitle was provided (for example, either in `\title[]{<title>}` or `\title{<title>}`).